# MongoDB `GET_LOCK` Solution in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, oauth, locking, blocking

I am trying to find a solution to prevent race conditions in my application logic (specifically when renewing an OAuth access token) and my back-end database happens to be mongodb.

Coming from a MySQL background, I'm used to using `GET_LOCK` and it's related functions to handle blocking in PHP.  Does Mongo have any analog to MySQL's `GET_LOCK` function, or will I have to use PHP's file locking or something similar?

Is `flock()` a good (or *proper*) alternative for this situation, or is that meant only for use when reading and writing to files?

Edit:

The race condition I am trying to prevent is the following:

1. Instance A notices OAuth access token nearing expiration
2. Instance B notices OAuth access token nearing expiration
3. Instance A requests refreshed OAuth access token from remote server and obtains one
4. Instance B requests refreshed OAuth access token from the same server and is rejected (server potentially invalidates access token from step 3 as security precaution)
5. Instance A saves result back to database
6. Instance B saves result back to database

Comment: race condition on PHP? what are you talking about?

Comment: Why lock anything? Locking a database is bad, transactions are good. MongoDB supports atomic actions: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-ApplyingtoMultipleObjectsAtOnce

Comment: Sorry I should clarify...  I mean to block access to a document containing an OAuth access token while the token is being refreshed and then allow access to it after the new access token is in place.  The race condition I aim to fix is on in which two processes notice an expired or nearly-expired access token and attempt to both refresh to the token with a new one...  one of the tokens will be valid and one will be invalid.  furthermore, the oauth server may invalidate both thinking that there is an attack occurring (an illegitimate oauth consumer trying to use an already-used refresh token)

Comment: I'd rather not lock the entire database...  it would be nice if I could lock a single document though.  

I cannot use an atomic operation because MongoDB isn't going to be able to communicate with the OAuth server and refresh the token for me.  That must be done in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simulate a named mutex or lock using MongoDB, I would suggest using [findAndModify](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command) by creating a special collection for it and having a document, you can even call it db.my_lock.

```
db.my_lock.save({"IMREFRESHINGAUTHTOKEN":false});
```

Now, between steps 2 and 3 add a findAndModify to grab the "lock":

```
db.my_lock.findAndModify(
        query: {"IMREFRESHINGAUTHTOKEN":false},
        update: {$set: {"IMREFRESHINGAUTHTOKEN": true}, ...}
);
```

If you get to the "lock" first, you will get back this object (and you will get to set the first field to true - I recommend setting a second field with timestamp or connection number or process ID or some other identifier which will allow cleaning up after a crashed process so it won't hold a lock forever).

If you "lose" the race you will get back nothing that matches "IMREFRESHINGAUTHTOKEN":false and you'll know you lost the race and give up (or check the timestamp of the lock and maybe try to see if it's old and stale).

This describes a stand-alone single lock on the whole "collection" - of course you can implement this as an extra field on the stored OAuth token and have as many of them being refreshed at a time as there are threads noticing they are expiring.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if the client crashes and holds a lock forever?

Comment: that's a reason to set a timestamp when "taking" the lock and periodically check that no lock is held longer than expected period, or set time and pid of who has it so it can be checked if the process still exists.